# Displayed dimensions of the edges are different than in object mode

Tags: dimensions

Just a beginner question here about dimensions. As an exercise I wanted to create a house and started with a block. The block was supposed to be 20m long, 3m high and 6m deep. I entered these values in object mode:

[image: changing dimensions in object mode]

Then I wanted to continue changing the shape in edit mode to progress with the house design but I saw that the displayed dimensions of the edges were completely different than in object mode:

[image: local dimensions of edges are different]

...however, if I switch to "global" in the side menu under "transform" the dimensions become correct again...:

[image]

Can anybody tell me what's going on here? Why are the values different?

Thanks in advance for helping me out.